# $|f(x)g(x)| = |(f(x)||g(x)|$

Tags: absolute-value

I was wondering if $|f(x)g(x)| = |f(x)| |(g(x)|$ is true all the time as in the case of real numbers.

I was not convinced enough that that was true.

But I can't think of any counterexample.

Thank you.

Comment: I also believe it is a duplicate in the end, but one comment I think is in order is that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are, as I'm sure you're assuming, real numbers, so as you even pointed out in your question statement we have $|f(x)g(x)|=|f(x)|\cdot |g(x)|$.

Comment: @Hayden:  The wording "as in the case of real numbers" suggests the OP is asking if the equality also holds in a more general setting ("all the time").  It does hold in more general settings (such as in the case of complex numbers), and it is a property that we require of norms generally in settings like Banach algebras.  Strictly speaking we need *some* context to say whether the equality is true or false.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, you may be right.  More context is definitely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Its is enough to prove it for the squares of the absolute values. And $\lvert z\rvert^2=z\bar z$.

Answer (score 0):

For each $x$, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are real (or complex) numbers. So the equality is precisely that of real (or complex) numbers.