# Is the $\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|$ always equivalent to $\frac{\left|f(x)\right|}{\left|g(x)\right|}$

Tags: absolute-value

Can I split the modulus of a rational function into two parts like this

$$
\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=\frac{\left|f(x)\right|}{\left|g(x)\right|}
\
$$

Is this statement always true for any function (or at least for polynomials)

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Of course, we need $g(x) \neq 0$ for the equation to be well-defined.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633642/prove-that-the-absolute-value-of-a-product-is-the-product-of-the-absolute-values and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373103/fxgx-fxgx

Comment: Equivalent is not the right word, maybe you mean equal. Equivalent you use to say that two relations are the same. But there are no relations involved here.

Comment: Is that true for any two given real numbers ? $|\frac{a}{b}| =  \frac{|a|}{|b|}$?

Comment: @leonbloy I know it would always be true for number so I suppose it should be for functions too, since functions give out some numbers. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks for editing my post, I managed to figure out how to do fractions, but how do you get the absolute value sign?

Comment: @NumberCruncher: It is "\left| hey \right|" $\to \left| hey \right|$ the left and right adjust the height correctly, if you are not concerned with height of the expression you can just use "|hey|" but it will look strange if you have fractions since they are usually higher than usual height.

Comment: @mathreadler \left| Thank \right| you for that